# Number of Symmetric matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $S_m(q)$ denote the space of all $m\times m$ symmetric matrices over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of size $q$. What is the number of matrices $A=(a_{ij})\in S_m(q)$ of rank at most $3$ and $a_{11} + a_{22}\neq 0$.

Comment: "size $q$" should be "size $m$"?

Comment: Here is a paper that counts for each fixed rank $r$ how many symmetric matrices there are- this ignores your last condition http://www.math.clemson.edu/~kevja/REU/2004/SymmetricRankRMatrices.pdf

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson >Sorry for the confusion. I meant there the size of the field. But I will change it.

Comment: @VladMatei Here is an extra condition on the diagonal elements of those matrices, i.e. $a_{11} +a_{22}\neq 0$

Comment: Have you looked at small values of $m$?  If a pattern shows itself, that would be encouraging.  Nothing about the questions suggests to me it will have a nice answer, but I haven't really got much intuition for the question.

Comment: @ Hugh Thomas I to find it tough. But could we show that this number will be strictly larger than the number of symmetric matrices of rank at most 3 with $a_{11}\neq 0$?